# DB2 SQL, cant define column as

Tags: db2

I have some SQLthat is part of that is a section of a with statement
And I keep getting an error that "NEWID" is not valid in the context where it is used sqlstate 42703.

**Update**: The error has been comming from the group by clause using a having function I didnt put in the original code as I thought it wasnt the issue.So I updated the code to show the full version.

Does anyone know what the problem is with the statement?

```
HATSTABLE1 (HATId, NewID) as (
select HA.HATId as "ID",
round(
  cast(
    sum(
      case when HA.ID = 4 or
        HA.ID < 0
        then 1 else 0 end
    ) AS FLOAT
  ) / count(*) * 100,
  2
) AS NewID
from Hats T
   join Heads HD on 
      T.ID=HD.HatID
group by T.ID
having NewID >1
```

Comment: `NewId` is not the same as `"NewID"`.

Comment: I have tried changing "NewID" to "NewId" but this gave me the same issue

Comment: `NewId` is not the same as `"NewId"` either. SQL identifiers are implicitly converted to upper case, but enclosing them in double quotes makes them case-sensitive.

Comment: This was helpful, but I cant upvote this comment

Comment: First, `group by T.ID` but T.ID is not in the SELECT list.

Comment: Second, `having NewID >1` but NewID is not in Hats nor Heads. It needs to be `having round(
  cast(
    sum(
      case when HA.ID = 4 or
        HA.ID < 0
        then 1 else 0 end
    ) AS FLOAT
  ) / count(*) * 100,
  2 ) >1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it

```
with tmp as (
select T.HATId as "ID", 
sum(case when T.ID = 4 or HA.ID < 0 then 1 else 0 end) as sum1, 
count(*) as nb
from Hats T
group by T.HATId 
)
select HATId, round(cast(sum1 as decimal)/ nb * 100, 2) NewID
from tmp
```